# Apache SSI, find user Screen Resolution

Tags: mobile, user-agent, ssi, apache2.2

I have a script that can select HTML to be served to the user in Apache SSI based on the user "User-Agent".

In that case I am giving the user that is coming from the mobile, content appropriate to the mobile (that all according to the google sudgestions).

The problem is that I would like to serve to the Tablets, Desktop version of the website and not a mobile one.

But the User-Agent only say Android for all android devices... 
What I would like it to find out what is the resolution of the user and to select according to it.

But HOW do I have this information in SSI?

Comment: As far as I know there is no standard way to do this on the server side (apache SSI). No browser will send you screen resolution in User-Agent headers, or any standard http headers. The best way to solve this problem will be using css media queries. http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so here is the answere for this question:

You can do it, but you will be limited to the script you put yourself.

You can download a Regex from here: http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/
And simple change the SetEnv in the end to match yours.

```
BrowserMatchNoCase (android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge\s|maemo|midp|mmp|mobile.+firefox|netfront|opera\sm(ob|in)i|palm(\sos)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows\s(ce|phone)|xda|xiino mobile_flag=1
BrowserMatchNoCase ^(1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a\swa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r\s|s\s)|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1\su|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp(\si|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-|\s|_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac(\s|\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt(\s|\/)|klon|kpt\s|kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg(\sg|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-|\s|o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v\s)|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v\s)|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-|\s)|webc|whit|wi(g\s|nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-) mobile_flag=1
```

For example here is my script. :)

And then you can use the mobile_flag in the SSI.

Answer (score 0):

You don't. The user agent does not contain information about the screen, nor does any other information in the HTTP request.

You could change your page's layout with CSS media queries, or do some JavaScript detection and then redirect the user to another page (or set some query parameters).

Comment: Actually you can, using DetectMobile and Rewrite with SetEnv :)